# What does "She’s nice to see and she’s soft to touch" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

I read a following poem in Les Miserables.

> There is a castle on a cloud,
> I like to go there in my sleep,
> Aren’t any floors for me to sweep,
> Not in my castle on a cloud.
>
> There is a room that’s full of toys,
> There are a hundred boys and girls,
> Nobody shouts or talks too loud,
> Not in my castle on a cloud.
>
> There is a lady all in white.
> Holds me and sings a lullaby,
> **She's nice to see and she’s soft to touch**,
> She says "Cosette, I love you very much."
>
> I know a place where no one's lost,
> I know a place where no one cries,
> Crying at all is not allowed,
> Not in my castle on a cloud
>
> -- *Les Miserables Musical* -  lyrics by Herbert Kretzmer

I have two explanations of "She's nice to see and she's soft to touch":

1. When she sees me, she is nice and she touches me softly.
2. I see her and she is nice and I touch her and she is soft.

I don't know which explanation is right and how to parse this sentence.

Answer (score 7):

"She's nice to see" means "It makes me happy when I see her" (as in "I'm glad to see you/It's nice to see you.")

"She's soft to touch" does indeed mean that her skin is soft when the speaker touches her, as was your second guess.

Comment: @WendiKidd.Actually, some of the sentences in this poem are quite difficult for me to understand clearly. Would you please describe this scene for me?

Comment: @user48070 If you have questions about other lines in the passage, feel free to ask another question (and please do explain what you think it might mean, as you did very well in this question :))